# python function not returning a list

Tags: python, recursion, return-value

I can't figure out why my implementation of Reverse Cuthill–McKee algorithm is returning
at the wrong place.
Basically, it produces the correct result, but when I run the code, it returns a different value.

Here is a full code with a graph, could some one please explain this behavior?

```
import numpy as np

A=np.diag(np.ones(8))

nzc=[[4],[2,5,7],[1,4],[6],[0,2],[1,7],[3],[1,5]]

for i in range(len(nzc)):
    for j in nzc[i]:
        A[i,j]=1

# define the Result queue
R = ["C"]*A.shape[0]


def getDegree(Graph):
    """
    find the degree of each node. That is the number
    of neighbours or connections.
    (number of non-zero elements) in each row minus 1.
    Graph is a Cubic Matrix.
    """
    degree = [0]*Graph.shape[0]
    for row in range(Graph.shape[0]):
        degree[row] = len(np.flatnonzero(Graph[row]))-1
    return degree
    
# find the starting point, the parent
degree = getDegree(A)

adj = getAdjcncy(A)
degree2=degree[::]
adj2 = adj[::]
digar=np.array(degree2)
pivots = list(np.where(digar == digar.min())[0])

def main_loop2(deg,start, adj,R):
    degcp=deg[:]
    digar=np.array(deg)
    # use np.where here to get indecies of minimums
    if start not in R:
        R.append(start)
        degcp.pop(start)
        if start in pivots:
           pivots.pop(start)
           print "p: ", pivots
    Q=adj[start]
    for idx, item in enumerate(Q):
        if item not in R:
            R.append(item)
            print "R", R
    print "starts", adj[R[-1]]
    Q=adj[R[-1]]
    if set(Q).issubset(set(R)) and len(R) < len(degcp) :
         print "will now look for new pivot"
         p = pivots[0]
         pivots.pop(0)
         print "pivots", pivots
         print "starting with" , p
         main_loop2(deg,p,adj,R)
         return 'this is never reached'
    elif len(R) < len(degcp):
         main_loop2(deg,R[-1],adj,R)
         return 'wrong'
    else:
         print "will return R"
         print type(R)
         return R      
    
inl=[]
Res = main_loop2(degree2,0, adj,inl)

print(Res)
```

#### output:

```
Degrees: [1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2]
0
p:  [3, 6]
R [0, 4]
starts [0, 2]
R  2 degcp 7
R [0, 4, 2]
starts [1, 4]
R  3 degcp 8
R [0, 4, 2, 1]
starts [2, 5, 7]
R  4 degcp 8
R [0, 4, 2, 1, 5]
R [0, 4, 2, 1, 5, 7]
starts [1, 5]
will now look for new pivot
pivots [6]
starting with 3
R [0, 4, 2, 1, 5, 7, 3, 6]
starts [3]
will return R
<type 'list'>
wrong
```

So the question is:
Why is the function working OK at all cycles of the recursion, but in the last one,
it returns the value `wrong`?
The output shows that the last `else` is only reached once, yet, a list is not returned, and I am quite helpless here.
I would appreciate if someone shed some light on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top level of your recursive call goes into here:

```
elif len(R) < len(degcp):
     main_loop2(deg,R[-1],adj,R)
     return 'wrong'
```

Whatever happens further inside the recursive call to `main_loop2` doesn't matter; when it comes back out, it will execute the `return 'wrong'` statement. You need to actually *return* the value the innermost call produces, all the way back out to the top level - it's not going to magically happen for you.

Did you mean to `return main_loop2(...)`?

Comment: on a second read, I now understand your answer. I see your point. I did not know that function called inside a function actually returns. Is this always the case with recursion or just with python?

Comment: Every language with function calls behaves this way (barring tail recursion optimization). Each call creates a new entry on the call stack, each `return` only returns to the previous stack frame ; whether that was a previous copy of itself or some other function entirely makes no difference.